# WordPress Blog Post "Read More" Link Not Taking Me To Actual Post

Tags: php, wordpress, posts, custom-wordpress-pages

A lot of articles here seem to deal with the "read more" link not displaying. Mine is displaying fine, it's just not actually taking us to a page that displays the full blog post. You can see how it's displaying here (Read More >>):

[image]

Right now when I click on "Read More >>" I get this:

[image]

In my code, in home.php, I'm displaying the blog posts like:

```
<?php 
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : '1';
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title', 'paged' => $paged);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
if ($posts->have_posts()):  while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format());
    echo "<div class='thepost'><p class='post-date'>".get_the_date()."</p>"; 
    echo "<h2 class='post-title'><a href=".get_permalink().">".get_the_title()."</a></h2>";
    //echo "<span class='post-image'>".the_post_thumbnail()."</span>";
    the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'post-image']);
    echo "<p class='post-paragraph'>".get_the_excerpt()."</p>"; 
    echo "<p><a href=".get_permalink()."><span class='read-more'>Read More >></span></a></p> </div>";

    endwhile;?>
```

So what do I need to change about this line: `echo "<p><a href=".get_permalink()."><span class='read-more'>Read More >></span></a></p></div>";` so that it links to the complete post that the user clicks on?

I've looked through [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) on how to customize the read more link, but I'm just finding

"Users can then continue reading more as you have enticed them with your summary introduction, by clicking on a link to the full article. Themes usually include this link in the title and the above methods will generate it by default trailing your teaser."

I must be missing something as I'm reading through the codex. Thanks!

**EDIT**: Inspecting the link:

[image]

**EDIT 2** Inspecting a broken page:

[image]

**EDIT 3**: full CSS (style.css): https://pastebin.com/TaUnemz9

**EDIT 4** full screenshot for individual blog post page:

[image]

Comment: for clearance, your read more link does not send the user to according post?   can you paste here site link ?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj I'm developing locally so I don't think pasting a link is going to help. But yes that is my problem.

Comment: According to another developer, there's nothing wrong with my html. The resulting page just has broken CSS. I pasted a link to my full CSS in the edit above.

Comment: Clear browser cache to load the new css. You should be able to tell if the link is correct from the URL you are sent to. If that is correct, it's just css, which seems to be the case.

Comment: check the files page.php and single.php have post loop code there or not

Comment: Hmm, the error message is gone but it still looks exactly like the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the key was that single post pages display via single.php according to the [WordPress Hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/).

So I needed to create a single.php file - most of the code for this file will still be the same as the code for home.php - it will still be displaying the header, the hero image, the nav menu, the footer, and the content will still be contained in a `<div>`.

What's different is that I need to take this out:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : '1';
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title', 'paged' => $paged);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

And change the WordPress loop from this: `if ($posts->have_posts()):  while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post();` to this: `if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();`. We already have the posts loaded, now we just need to display them.

Whatever WP functions I needed to get / echo changes depending on how displaying a single post is different from displaying multiple posts. I can take out:

```
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format());
        echo "<p class='post-paragraph'>".get_the_excerpt()."</p>"; 
        echo "<p><a href=".get_permalink()."><span class='read-more'>Read More >></span></a></p> </div>";
```

Since I don't need them anymore.

The key is that links work differently in WordPress than basic HTML. It's not like in HTML where if you have  `<a href="post-page.html">Read More</a>`, you'll be taken to post-page.html when you click on Read More. Since it's a WP site, it's using PHP and you wrap the permalink in an `<a>` tag using the WP function `.get_permalink().`. Then the permalink will take you to single.php.

Answer (score 1):

Three things first of all I can't told you exact what is problem without any proper link.but as i was going through closely of your screenshot.I found that

you get link like http://localhost/fourth-blog-post 
When you click on read more button.

but it should be like this http://localhost/blog/fourth-blog-post

Because its single post of all your posts and its comes from single.php file,
now you can do two things first check url of your post via admin panel where your post is appear. second if it matches the second url which i mentioned on above link. then you should try the_permalink() function at the place of get_permalink() for more information you can visit.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

because get_permalink() should not be use with in loop. and it should be the_permalink() with in the loop.

I hope it will help you:)

Comment: Yeah I copied and pasted my code from home.php (the blog page) into single.php but my problem is still the link. The link for "Read More" - the URL for that page looks like `http://localhost/hello-world/`. I'm not sure why it's going to "hello-world" and not `http://localhost/blog/fourth-blog-post`. See the above edit for a full screenshot of the page. You'll also notice that it's displaying all of the blog posts. So that means somewhere in single.php, I need to make an adjustment so that only the selected post gets displayed. Here's a link to my single.php file: https://pastebin.com/7LkJN6TY

Comment: let me check this and give me some moment i'll back to you.

Comment: Bro your code not working because at very first you commented the while loop at line no. 8//while (have_posts()) : the_post(); remove doble slashes  and you don't need custom query in single.php file because it takes default loop and get only one post on single.php. why are you adding custom query at single.php file

Comment: Uncommenting that gives me an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/themes/dynamictransit/single.php on line 231` - sorry where is the custom query?

Comment: because you commented endwhile as well thats why you got this error. on line no. 230

Comment: Uncommenting this gets rid of the error message, but it still displays exactly like the screenshot above.

Comment: And have you try the_permalink() function at the place of get_permalink();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141726/discussion-between-happyhands31-and-suraj-menariya).

Comment: I tried this, starting on line 233 in single.php: pastebin.com/LwNVwJxL You can see what I tried on line 12

Comment: Lets continue on chat...with in 1 hour currently i am singin out.

Comment: I tried to contact you via chat but it looks like you're not in the chatroom